# On Importing tlb file function name changed

Tags: c#, c++, tlbimp

I have a Dll built in C# code and due to some need I want to use it with C++ code.

After a long search I found a solution and created `abcd.tlb` from my `abcd.dll` file using `RegASM.exe`.

I imported the *tlb* file in my C++ project and everything worked fine.

But after sometime when I again generated the *tlb* file from the same **C#** code and imported the new *tlb* file in my old **C++** code, the old C++ code has stopped compiling due to function name mismatch. To my surprise the name of one of the function has changed from `GetUrl` to `Geturl` in *.tlh* file.

When I used the same code in another machine and generated *tlb* file, it worked fine.

**Does anyone has any clue as why the function name has been changed on a particular machine at the time of *.tlh* generation?**

Comment: Hmm, no, it didn't happen at import time.  The general problem with unexpected case changes in type libraries is described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26304805/17034).